# QMessageBox is not positioned correctly when shown during startup

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qmessagebox

I have a program that takes one command line parameter (the file to load). If something goes wrong while loading the file, a `QMessageBox` is shown. It's not placed correctly (not centered on the `MainWindow`), most probably because the `show()` process is not finished yet when the load function is called.

I had the following code in `main.cpp`

```
MainWindow mainWindow;
mainWindow.show();

QStringList arguments = QCoreApplication::arguments();
if (arguments.count() > 1) {
    mainWindow.loadTournament(arguments[1]);
}

return app.exec();
```

I then tried to add

```
QApplication::processEvents();
```

before the load function call, but it doesn't change anything.

I also tried to add

```
QStringList arguments = QCoreApplication::arguments();
if (arguments.count() > 1) {
    loadTournament(arguments[1]);
}
```

to the end of the main window's constructor, but the behavior is exactly the same, also with a `QApplication::processEvents();` before.

I then tried to use a `QTimer` with the following code added to the end of the constructor:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &MainWindow::checkLoadTournament);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::checkLoadTournament()
{
    QStringList arguments = QCoreApplication::arguments();
    if (arguments.count() > 1) {
        loadTournament(arguments[1]);
    }
}
```

added. This also produces the very same wrong placement of the `QMessageBox`.

If I increase the `QTimer` wait value (to e. g. 100 msecs), it works. But this seems a bit hacky to me, because I can't be sure if the main window is actually shown within this period of time.

Is there a way to either know if the main window showing and placement is done and finished correctly and wait for this to be done before showing the `QMessageBox` or to place it to the right position before?

Edit: Here's a SSCCE:

main.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.loadTournament();
    return app.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow();
    void loadTournament();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    resize(900, 700);
}

void MainWindow::loadTournament()
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("foo"), tr("bar"), QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

The message box does not appear centered on the main window. Dependant on where I put my console window from where I start it (and the main window is placed), the difference can be quite big.

Comment: One thing to try would be to move the QMessageBox code (or perhaps just a QTimer::singleShot(0, this, ShowTheMessageDialog()) call into the showEvent(QShowEvent*) method of the window; that way it won't run until after the window is visible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way … showEvent is not only called when the window is set up, but also e. g. when it's minimized and restored again …

Comment: You have not shown the code which actually deals with `QMessageBox`. How are you doing that? Do you create the object of `QMessageBox` yourself and call its `exec` method or do you use one of `QMessageBox`'s static methods (`QMessageBox::information`, `QMessageBox::question` etc)? `QMessageBox` should be centered on its parent so make sure you set the right parent if you don't use static methods or make sure you pass the pointer to `MainWindow` to the first argument of the static method otherwise.

Comment: @TobiasLeupold that's easy enough to handle by testing/setting a boolean variable, so that the QMessageBox code is only executing the first time showEvent() is called.

Comment: @Dmitry: The message box is setup via `QMessageBox messageBox(this)` and later executed by `messageBox.exec()`, it's not the static version. But the static functions also take a parent as the first argument, so this shouldn't matter …

Comment: I can't replicate this. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @thuga: See my edit :-)

Comment: Works fine for me on windows 7. The messagebox is centered on the mainwindow.

Comment: I'm on Linux on X11/KDE. Most probably, it depends on the window manager then.

Comment: You could try calling `ensurePolished` on your main window before showing the messagebox, but I doubt it will work. Your best bet is to either calculate the correct position yourself, or to show it inside the `showEvent` of your main window. Just make sure to set a flag inside the `showEvent` to know that it is the first time that the window is shown.

Comment: Calling `ensurePolished` doesn't change the behavior … I'll try to check the show() event.

Comment: I'll tried to add both show() and showEvent() to my main window. Both functions are actually called _before_ the loadTournament() call happens. So setting some variable inside one of those functions won't help either, as they are called before loadTournament() anyway …

Comment: I'm having the same issues with Linux X11/KDE with multiple monitors.  QMessageBox always appears in my top left monitor first, then always appears on the monitor that the box was before a move.  It's driving me crazy because the message box locks up the parent making my software seem buggy, diminishing the user experience.